# R quantmod candlesticks do not plot; OHLC data seems unrecognized

Tags: r, data-visualization, quantmod

I am following a basic tutorial for R's `quantmod` package. I run into trouble using the candlestick plots however. It appears that `chartSeries` does not recognize the data I download as OHLC.
I just updated to R 3.1.0 and redownloaded the involved packages. My machine is Windows 7 64-bit.

Minimum example follows. Can anyone make sense of this?

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("YHOO")
chartSeries(YHOO, type='candlesticks')
```

Expected output: candlesticks. Received output: line plot with volume.

```
> head(YHOO)
           YHOO.Open YHOO.High YHOO.Low YHOO.Close YHOO.Volume YHOO.Adjusted
2007-01-03     25.85     26.26    25.26      25.61    26352700         25.61
2007-01-04     25.64     26.92    25.52      26.85    32512200         26.85
2007-01-05     26.70     27.87    26.66      27.74    64264600         27.74
2007-01-08     27.70     28.04    27.43      27.92    25713700         27.92
2007-01-09     28.00     28.05    27.41      27.58    25621500         27.58
2007-01-10     27.48     28.92    27.44      28.70    40240000         28.70
```

Additional information: This behavior is the same on my Windows 7, 64 bit machine. I'm running R 3.1.0 (April 2014) and quantmod 0.3-214 (from 2012-12) there. My VM where the behavior is identical is running Debian unstable with the same version numbers for R and quantmod.

Comment: Would this be more appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. If so, could it be moved there or is 'close + repost' the way to go?
In any case: I just tested this on a Debian unstable VM as well and the behavior is identical.

Thank you for editing!

Comment: Seems some problem with your installation. Works fine for me.

Comment: Some problem with my installation on both Windows and the Debian VM? I'm installing via install.packages('quantmod') which pulls the other libraries. What could possibly go wrong there?
Is it possible that there is a problem with the date format and my computer locale?